# Is it better to preallocate and reassign variables or check for existence and create them after?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I have a sort of programming philosophy question about what is the "better" or "more Pythonic" way to assign variables.

**In a situation where variables may not be assigned by function but must exist (at least as placeholders) later, which option is better?**

1. **Pre-assign them all and then reassign some in the function** or
2. **At the end of the function only assign the ones theretofore unassigned**

I will give an example and describe my specific situation but hope someone can answer the general question and not just optimize this example code.

### Example:

`Image.merge('RGB', bands)` requires three input images (one of each color) from `image_normalization()` or `Image.new()` but some of my arrays only have 1-2 colors in them. I can either (1) initialize all three images at the beginning and then replace/resize them based on the input or (2) check for missing colors at the end and only create the placeholders needed.

#### 1. Preallocate and reassign:

```py
def image_merge(inputArray:np.ndarray, noOfColors:int) -> Image.Image:

    img0 = Image.new('L',(1,1),0)
    img1 = Image.new('L',(1,1),0)
    img2 = Image.new('L',(1,1),0)

    for colorNumber in range(noOfColors):
        globals()[f'img{colorNumber}'] = image_normalization(inputArray, colorNumber)
    
    if img1.size == 1: img1 = Image.new('L',img0.size,0)
    if img2.size == 1: img2 = Image.new('L',img0.size,0)

    imgMerge = Image.merge('RGB', (img0, img1, img2))
    return imgMerge
```

#### 2. Wait until the end and only create if necessary:

```py
def image_merge(inputArray:np.ndarray, noOfColors:int) -> Image.Image:

    for colorNumber in range(noOfColors):
        globals()[f'img{colorNumber}'] = image_normalization(inputArray, colorNumber)
    
    if 'img1' not in globals(): globals()['img1'] = Image.new('L',img0.size,0)
    if 'img2' not in globals(): globals()['img2'] = Image.new('L',img0.size,0)

    imgMerge = Image.merge('RGB', (img0, img1, img2))
    return imgMerge
```

Another version of "waiting to the end" would be using `try` blocks in place of the `if` statements, i.e.:

```py
try: img1
except: img1 = Image.new('L',img0.size,0)
try: img2
except: img2 = Image.new('L',img0.size,0)
```

#### More context:

I'm using the [`Pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module to create an RGB image from 1-3 arrays of pixel intensities. The `image_normalization` function creates a monochromatic image from an array and the `Image.merge()` function creates an RGB image from 3 monochromatic images (one of each color: red, green, & blue), all with the same dimensions. However, some of my input arrays only contain information for 1-2 colors, thus I need to create 1-2 placeholder arrays with `Image.new()` before the merge.

Comment: If you want a global list of images and a function to manipulate them, I would pass that list as a parameter to the function rather than try to establish global context from within a function.

Comment: You shouldn't be injecting variables into the global namespace like this in the first place. Add entries to a global `dict` instead: `images[colorNumber] = image_normalization(...)`, for example. Otherwise, step 2 is better: it avoids creating objects that may only exist until they are discarded.

Comment: That's helpful, @chepner. My linter gets mad if I don't preallocate (which is what sent me down this path) and I think the `dict` implementation would alleviate that too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that neither of these options (as presented above) are particularly pythonic, and in general I'd caution away from variable assignment by operating on `globals()`. It can make it a lot harder to understand what is going on and allows the introduction of some odd bugs (for example, what if your function gets called accidentally with a much higher value for `noColors`? You're potentially allocating an arbitrary amount of memory when you are explicitly only using a very small subset of that)

Here's an alternative:

```py
# Using your camelCase convention
def image_merge(inputArray:np.ndarray, noOfColors:int, requiredColors: int = 3) -> Image.Image:
    images = []

    for colorNumber in range(min(noOfColors, requiredColors)):
        images.append(image_normalization(inputArray, colorNumber))
    
    if len(images) == 0:
        # no colours specified- raise exception?
        raise Exception("yikes")

    while len(images) < requiredColors:
        images.append(Image.new('L', images[0].size, 0))

    imgMerge = Image.merge('RGB', tuple(*images))
    return imgMerge
```

In this case, you're able to avoid using any "magic" and make it abundantly clear from reading the code what is actually going on and how and why you're creating your default cases.